# Find out which of three Select boxes is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have three three select fields for one entity attribute. As the picture below shows ([**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HShHg/171/)).[image]

I am trying to find a way to detect which of the select fields has been used (which is the last one the user clicked on) and get (alert it) the number of this select box (0, 1, 2) and the value selected.

The aim of this code is to tell the server side of select boxes it needs to consider when saving the form. I will send the data via Ajax (which I know how to, I need only the part to figure out which of the select box it has been used)

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label control-label required">Contenu de l'annonce</label>
<div class="col-sm-10 form-inline">

<select id="_D1_H1">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label1</option>
<option value="Value1d">Value1d</option>
<option value="Value2">Value2</option>
<option value="Value3">Value3</option>
</select>

<select id="D1_H2">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label2</option>
<option value="Value4">Value4</option>
<option value="Value5">Value5</option>
</select>

<select id="D1_H3">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label3</option>
<option value="Value6">Value6</option>
</select>

</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the actual aim of the exercise? To not submit before all are filled or to only allow one selection? Please elaborate. It sounds right now as an X/Y problem

Comment: @mplungjan ok, I will update the question.

Comment: @mplungjan I updated the question. The solution of Programmer21 is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.drp').change(function() {
 let selectedDropdown = $(this).attr('id');
 let selectedValue = $(this).val();
 alert(selectedDropdown);
 alert(selectedValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label control-label required">Contenu de l'annonce</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 form-inline">

        <select class="drp" id="_D1_H1">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label1</option>
<option value="Value1d">Value1d</option>
<option value="Value2">Value2</option>
<option value="Value3">Value3</option>
</select>

        <select class="drp" id="D1_H2">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label2</option>
<option value="Value4">Value4</option>
<option value="Value5">Value5</option>
</select>

        <select class="drp" id="D1_H3">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label3</option>
<option value="Value6">Value6</option>
</select>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's what I am looking for. I just need to figure out how to return the remaining select boxes to their label value.

Answer (score 1):

You can get index with `index()` method and value with `val()`

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var n = $(this).index()
  var val = $(this).val();

  console.log(n + ' ' + val)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label control-label required">Contenu de l'annonce</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 form-inline">
    <select id="_D1_H1">
      <option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label1</option>
      <option value="Value1d">Value1d</option>
      <option value="Value2">Value2</option>
      <option value="Value3">Value3</option>
    </select>

    <select id="D1_H2">
      <option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label2</option>
      <option value="Value4">Value4</option>
      <option value="Value5">Value5</option>
    </select>

    <select id="D1_H3">
      <option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label3</option>
      <option value="Value6">Value6</option>
    </select>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers seem fine, I'm just adding a pure js alternative. I've used data attributes to store the order when adding event listeners but you might want to do that when you're building your markup, depending on what your specific situation is.

```js
function addEventListeners() {
  selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for (i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    selects[i].setAttribute('data-pos', i);
    selects[i].addEventListener('change', alertChange);
  }
}

function alertChange() {
  console.log('Select number: ' + this.getAttribute('data-pos') + ' changed to value: ' + this.value + '.');
}

addEventListeners();
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label control-label required">Contenu de l'annonce</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 form-inline">

    <select id="_D1_H1">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label1</option>
<option value="Value1d">Value1d</option>
<option value="Value2">Value2</option>
<option value="Value3">Value3</option>
</select>

    <select id="D1_H2">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label2</option>
<option value="Value4">Value4</option>
<option value="Value5">Value5</option>
</select>

    <select id="D1_H3">
<option value="" disabled="" selected="" hidden="">label3</option>
<option value="Value6">Value6</option>
</select>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I read your update, you likely want

```js
// for some reason I could not use the sel.defaultSelected
// so I save the index at load
$(function() {
  $("select").each(function() {
    $(this).data("def", this.selectedIndex);
  });

  $("#send").on("click", function() {
    var changed = [];
    $("select").each(function(i, sel) {
      if (sel.selectedIndex != $(this).data("def")) changed.push([i, sel.value])
    });
    console.log(changed);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label control-label required">Contenu de l'annonce</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 form-inline">

    <select id="_D1_H1">
      <option value="">label1</option>
      <option value="Value1d" selected>Value1d</option>
      <option value="Value2">Value2</option>
      <option value="Value3">Value3</option>
    </select>

    <select id="D1_H2">
      <option value="">label2</option>
      <option value="Value4">Value4</option>
      <option value="Value5">Value5</option>
    </select>

    <select id="D1_H3">
      <option value="">label3</option>
      <option value="Value6">Value6</option>
    </select>

  </div>
</div>
<button id="send" type="button">Send</button>
```